# How to make unstoppable and unhidden Progroess Dialog unless AsyncTask completes

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I am using AsynTask as background service.

If user clicks anywhere on Activity, the Progress-dialog vanishes, I want it to be on screen as I do not want user to be able to interact further within the activity if he has clicked the login button and started the login service.

Here is the image

[image]

The Progress-dialog must be visible to user until the background task or thread or service completes. So that user must wait for any further interaction with the application unless the service completes.

Comment: read the documentation, you'll find setCancelOnTouchOutside

Comment: you need to setInderminate as true, then it will indeterminately rotate on the screen. You can set dialog.dismiss() when you think the login is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add

```
progress-dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
progress-dialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                        return keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Correct, except you can't have dashes in variables names.